# How to make a software portable with C#?

Tags: c#

I'm coding a simple application that I need to be portable (the user can just run it by clicking on the .exe without having to run a installer).

All the other questions on this subject that I found on StackOverflow wants to make .NET Framework "bundable" with the software, but I don't need that.

A workaround that I found is going to /bin/Debug on the project folder and use the .exe there, but that seems "wrong". Is there another way to make a software written in C# portable?

Thanks!

**EDIT:** Okay, I'm really dumb and I asked all the wrong questions. However, your answers pointed me to the right direction. I wanted to know how to generate the .exe to send to my friends. What I had to do is change this to "Release" and press F6. I added this so if someone with the same "doubts" that I had can find the answer easly. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: It's the opposite: any application is portable by default. Just don't make it relying on an installer and you're fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Going to bin/Debug and using the DLL there *is* wrong.

Instead, build and copy the one from bin/Release.

If there's anything else inside the folder, though (except *.pdb), then beware.  Your application might need those additional files.  For example, the app.config.

Comment: Even though it's perfectly correct - it doesn't have anything to do with the question (the question was about portability)

Comment: @zerkms: Huh?  The question says "A workaround that I found is going to /bin/Debug on the project folder and use the .exe there, but that seems "wrong"."  The question is whether that's appropriate, and the answer is "Yes, except in one detail."

Comment: I must be missing something then :-S

Answer (score 2):

All .NET applications are "portable" as long as the machine you are running it on has the version of .NET you are targeting (or a compatible version).  The key here is to make sure that your application does not depend on things that an installer would take care of for you to make your application work.  Examples include: registered DLLs (like Interop assemblies), registry keys, or components that must be found in certain locations (such as having something stored in user's AppData folder).

Answer (score 1):

As long as the machine you want to run it on has .NET framework, you can make any .NET application portable. If the app you're making has no dependencies other than .NET then it's fully portable already. Even if it does have dependencies just include those with the executable.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Zerkms's comment:

Every *software* is portable by default. Installers are a way of telling to program to search for resources in a certain place, meaning that if the place isn't there, eg: C:\Windows then the program won't be able to run.

So as long as you have the application have the resources already within the exe or a root folder search (so where the program is, rather then where it should be) then you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using default controls, it should be fine as long as your software's running framework version is installed on the computer. If you're using 3rd party controls, you can emded the dll's into the .exe upon compiling. Do note that the more dll's you embed, the bigger the .exe file will be.

Comment: There's no compiler option to embed DLLs.  You can use a tool like `ILMerge` later, but it has considerable restrictions.

Comment: @BenVoigt I may have described my method wrong but I actually did it. I placed the DLL's into the resources folder and set the Build Action of the resource to Embedded Resource. Then add a chunk of code to load the DLL from the folder when the software needs it.

Comment: @zerkms I'm purely asking, so yeah, would it make sense if you have a smaller file size when you emded files into 1 file? I haven't done this before, but if you have done so, please do share.